# Ajax AutoCompleteExtender textbox not firing text change event in Edge Browser

Tags: asp.net, ajax, microsoft-edge, autocompleteextender

I am using Ajax AutoCompleteExtender on a textbox(ASP.NET) and I have wired up the text change event. When I type in the textbox system is able to successfully fetch the data from an asmx method but the text change event associated with the auto complete text box is not getting fired. This is only happening in Edge browser. I tested the site in chrome and IE and it is working absolutely fine.  To add this issue started to appear when I upgraded to the latest version of Ajax Control Kit. Also the text change event gets fired(edge) when I click on the submit button. It's something like the text change event is getting fired when some other event is fired.

Below is the code snippet.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="AutoTxtCompany" runat="server" aria-describedby="ContentPlaceHolder1_rfvCustomerCompany" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="ui-autocomplete-input ui-widget ui-widget-content comboBoxDimensionsTextBox" OnTextChanged="AutoTxtCompany_TextChanged" aria-required="true" />  
<asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="autoextAutoTxtCompany" BehaviorID="autoextcompanyautocomplete" runat="server" TargetControlID="AutoTxtCompany" MinimumPrefixLength="1" EnableCaching="false"
CompletionSetCount="5000" CompletionInterval="100" ServiceMethod="getCompanyList"                       CompletionListCssClass="autocomplete_completionListElement" ServicePath="~/FrontEnd/AutoComplete.asmx" UseContextKey="true" FirstRowSelected="true">
</asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the AutoCompleteExtender control's **OnClientItemSelected** event to fire the Textbox TextChanged event. Code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function DoTextChangedPostBack(source, eventArgs) {
        var hfield = $get('<%=AutoTxtCompany.ClientID%>');
        hfield.value = eventArgs.get_value();
        __doPostBack("<%=AutoTxtCompany.ID%>", "TextChanged");
    }
</script>
<div>           
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:TextBox ID="AutoTxtCompany" runat="server" aria-describedby="ContentPlaceHolder1_rfvCustomerCompany" 
        AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="ui-autocomplete-input ui-widget ui-widget-content comboBoxDimensionsTextBox" 
        OnTextChanged="AutoTxtCompany_TextChanged" aria-required="true" />  
    <ajaxtoolkit:autocompleteextender id="autoextAutoTxtCompany" behaviorid="autoextcompanyautocomplete" runat="server"
        targetcontrolid="AutoTxtCompany" minimumprefixlength="1" enablecaching="false"
        completionsetcount="5000" completioninterval="100" servicemethod="getCompanyList" 
        completionlistcssclass="autocomplete_completionListElement" servicepath="FrontEnd/AutoComplete.asmx" 
            OnClientItemSelected="DoTextChangedPostBack" 
        usecontextkey="true" firstrowselected="true">
    </ajaxtoolkit:autocompleteextender>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. It worked correctly. But shouldn't this be done automatically? I have raised a concern with the devExpress team on this. Let's see what they have to say.